script for AutoHotKey v2 that is searching for a file in all drives
i want a script for AHK v2 that is searching for a file in all drives named "autorun.inf" that contains the line "label=jhon" and if the script found the file to search only in the same drive for a file named "userData.txt" that contains the line "id=11111" and the line "stickerId=2222"
if the script found the two files in the same drive to run cmd. and if not to show a message "it's not youre program"
thanks
i asked chatbot ai he gave me this script but its not working
#Requires AutoHotkey v2.0
DriveGet Drives List

for index Drive in Drives {
    autorunPath := drive . "\autrun.inf"
    if FileExist(autorunPath) {
        FileRead autorunContent %autoPath%
        if InSrt(autorunContent, "[autorun]") && InStr(autorunContent, "label=jhon") {
            userDataPath := drive . "\userData.txt"
            if FileExist(userDataPath) {
                FileRead userDataContent %userDataPath%
                if InStr(userDataContent, "clientId=38412") && InStr(userDataContent, "stickerId=28270") {
                    Run "cmd.exe"
                }
                Else MsgBox 'it's not youre program', 'message', 'Icon!'
                }
            }
        }
}


the program just dosent work, It shows me a lot of errors
sorry for my bad english
